# TextBox not displayed when rendering form with Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've just begun learning ASP MVC 4, and I'm working on a basic exercise, which is a book hosting website.

I'm currently working on a controller for adding a new book to the repository. The view for the appropriate action is strongly-typed to the `Book` class as its model. `Book` is a very simple model consisting of title, author and so forth.

My `AddBook` controller currently looks like this: (I haven't implemented any database insertion logic on POST, yet)

```
public class AddBookController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddBook()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddBook(Book book)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

My view is also very simple:

```
@model Bookshare.Models.Book

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddBook";
}

Add a new book
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title);
    Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Author);
    Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PublishingCompany);
    Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReleaseYear);
    Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Summary);
}
```

And yet, when I call this action, all I can see is the "Add a new book" header and the submit button for the form. No text boxes whatsoever. This also happens if I use the plain old `Html.TextBox` syntax. Viewing the page's source reveals just an empty form tag.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are using the Html Helper is wrong. The `TextBoxFor` method is not a void method that you call like `Html.TextBoxFor(...);`. It returns an `MvcHtmlString` object that you want to write on the page. Therefore, you use it like below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title)
```

`@` in the above code is the equivalent of `Response.Write` in classic asp.

So, your Form in its simplest way should be like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Author)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PublishingCompany)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReleaseYear)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Summary)
}
```

But, that will render all TextBoxes next to each other without a Label, and without a placeholder for validation message. Replace each TextBox in your View with something like below to format them on the page properly and to add a Label and a Validation Message placeholder.

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
</div>
```

`EditorFor` will be rendered as TextBox for string properties.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that for the correct form you need only the following. The controller for the create method can be like this:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

My working view looks like this, your fields of course will be slightly different:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Book</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

With this I can see the form rendered in the browser.

Comment: Do you mean instantiating an empty Book object and pass it into the View on Get? I have already tried this, with no success.

Comment: You need to pass the `Book` object to the View as a parameter in the `return View(book)`.

Comment: After a bit of experimentation it seems that your controller looks ok, but the view needs some tweaking